# What does $ \frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{4} +\frac {1}{8} + \frac{1}{17}+\frac{1}{32}+... $ converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

While I was observing a well known following series a thought came to my mind and I felt its worth sharing here.

The series which I'm talking about is $$ \frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{4} +\frac {1}{8} +...\frac {1}{2^n} $$ which converges to $1$ as $n$ tends to infinity. This fact can be justified by considering it as a sum of infinite geometric series or by intuitively considering two points and checking this result ( Zeno's paradox).

Now if we disturb this nice series a bit and make it the following $$ \frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{4} +\frac {1}{8} + \frac{1}{17}+\frac{1}{32}+... $$ Here we have just replaced the term $\frac{1}{16}$ with $\frac{1}{17}$.

So, now what will this series converge to as number of terms in series tends to infinity ? Let us consider this infinite sum as equal to $x$ . Then, algebraically if I just add  $\frac{1}{16}$ and subtract $\frac{1}{17}$ both the sides then I get $$ x= 1 + \frac{1}{17}-\frac{1}{16} $$
$$x= 0.996323 $$.

Now if I consider this sum intuitively by taking two points and then covering half the distance between them, the a fourth, then an eighth, no matter $\frac{1}{16}$ is in the sum or $\frac{1}{17}$ , the sum really converges to $1$ only.

Then my question is that why both the approaches are giving contradicting results ? Is my approach using two points invalid ? If not , then can this manipulation be done generally by manipulating more than one (or all) terms like this and still not disturbing the result ?

Thanks for any help.

It would be appreciable if no calculus or any property of converging series is used while answering as I'm not familiar with this all now.

Comment: You have a *positive* series that converges. If you change **any** summand of it, as you did in your question, the new series will converge to something **different**, of course. I really didn't understand your "intuitively" approach.

Comment: @ DonAntonio I mean that if you will consider two points and cover half the distance between them, then cover one fourth distance between them and so on , according to me as we are adding infinite terms it will not make difference if I add 1/17 instead of 1/16 as it is smaller than 1/16 and after calculating the infinite sum it will converge to 1. I may be wrong as I've not read this topic in detail with rigor and just for curiosity asked this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you "cover up" 1/17 of the distance, there is more distance left than if you would have covered up 1/16 of the distance.  So when you take half the remaining distance, it's *more* in the first case than in the second.  You're not just changing one number, you're changing all subsequent numbers.

Comment: I'm not saying to take half the remaining distance. I'm just changing that term as mentioned. So don't take me wrong.

Comment: By the way if I would also take half the remaining distance and then again half the remaining distance, after summing it to infinite terms, I certainly think we will again approach 1 only.

Comment: If you're not taking half the remaining distance, then why does your intuition mislead you into thinking the sum adds to 1?

Comment: I thought that when we add 1/17 instead of 1//16 ,after adding larger & larger number of terms, the sum will approach 1. I may be wrong, but that was what I could imagine in my head. Also, as I mentioned in my last comment, considering half the remaining distance also reaffirms my argument (I found this more apt). In all, my intuition says that it is not a finite sum but an infinite one & thus after adding infinitely many terms, the sum approaches 1 as it is certainly less than 1 if we stop in between while calculating the sum .

Comment: I tried best to explain myself. I hope I will get any help in this matter. If not , I'll try to edit this question or post a new one. Sorry for discomfort

Comment: You are wrong.  You imagination is misleading you.  There's no reason for "adding larger and larger number of terms" should be 1, rather than some other number.  Why doesn't your imagination imagine that it adds to 2?

Comment: May be you are right , it was just a deception. Anyways I would reconsider this with greater detail. Thanks for your time and help.